# What is difference between all these git commands?

Tags: git

What is difference between all these git commands?

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git reset --hard HEAD^
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: Read in the documentation about how to specify [Git revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions).

Comment: It's not completely clear whether your question is about what `git reset` itself does, what the `--hard` flag adds *to* `git reset`, and/or the revision specifiers `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and the variants with suffixes.

Comment: I want to know about revision specifiers. HEAD, HEAD~1, HEAD^, and ORIG_HEAD

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --hard HEAD` simply takes back all your changes from your working tree (no backup)

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` takes you back to the parent of the current revision (no backup, no saving changes)

`git reset --hard HEAD^` same thing as the previous one. Syntactically different it is a little different. ^ is used to point parents on a merge commit whereas ~ is parents going back in revisions taking the first parent. So `HEAD~` = `HEAD^` but `HEAD~2` means 2 revisions back in history from current revision whereas `HEAD^2` takes the second parent of the current revision (assuming the current revision is a merge commit)

`git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` Takes you back (no backup) to the revision you were before your last checkout/merge/commit/revert/cherry-pick operation (no necessary parent-child relation to current revision). If you were on `branchA` and then you switched to `branchB` then `ORIG_HEAD` would be `branchA`... actually not the branch itself but the revision where it was at that moment. It has fallen out of use as the `HEAD@{1}` syntax is way more powerful because you can say other things like *where I was 3 revisions ago* with `HEAD@{3}`. So, if you were on `branchA`, switched to `branchB` then `branchC`, then `HEAD@{1}` would be `branchB`, `HEAD@{2}` would be branchA (again, not the branches, but the revisions they were pointing to at that moment. If the branch moves, this won't change the revision).